# How to connect devices from two different local networks

Tags: networking, router, routing

Hello networking specialist !

I have a "configuration" issue on my setup and I ask for help after some hours of research.

I have a modem, from my ISP, that I use to connect my Nas (Synology) (`ip: 192.168.1.112`)
it's a tp-link Archer 1600

`Ip : 192.168.1.1 with 255.255.255.0 sub mask.`

Main issue : I am not able to configure a VPN connection on this router.

So I recently buy a "travel" router (GL.iNet AR750 Creta) on which I can add an openVPN configuration. this modem is wired to my modem on it's WAN port (`192.168.1.121 Ip`)

my new router`Ip: 192.168.8.1 with mask 255.255.255.0`

I connect my Apple TV to the GL router with ip `192.168.8.180`.

The issue is that I cannot connect the Apple TV (`192.168.8.180`) to the NAS (`192.168.1.112`).
I know I can simply connect the Nas to the new router and it's ok. But I would really not prefer (I rather use the only port remaining to something else, plus I don't want the gas to go through VPN)

I don't have the feeling that It's not a complicated configuration, but I really need some advice.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you connect your AR750 **AP/router** to the WAN port of your TP-Link **AP/router**?

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible "route" to the solution you need. As I can't comment, I'll give my best shot to help you. I don't have specifics of each hardware you have, so the answer will be kind of "generic". I hope this can give you directions on solving your issue.

I'm assuming that your new routes is doing "NAT" (network address translation -- or hiding the local network from outside -- which, in turn, is the 192.168.1.x network). But the lack of setting up NAT also makes sense in being the reason for the issue. Too much technical info behind I'm afraid.

So here's what probably will help you:
1. on your ISP router (`192.168.1.112`), get into the settings and find **"routing"**, **"routing tables"**, **"static routes"**, something around this.

Once you find it, you'll add a static route like this:

```
Network: 192.168.8.0
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway (or "via"): 192.168.1.121
```

Notice the `192.168.1.x` IP you provide is your new router's IP in the NAS network. You're telling it where to find the `192.168.8.x` network.

2. on your new router, ensure you have NAT disabled. This means you are letting your ISP router do the NAT to whatever is going to the internet, and whatever navigates within your local network will be presented with their actual addresses. I am hoping your NAS will correctly translate connections coming from `192.168.8.x` aside the `192.168.1.x` immediate local network.
3. On your TV, ensure it is getting a Gateway IP Address (pointing to `192.168.8.1`). If it is being set up by DHCP, it should be getting it right. If manually set, then you'd have to add it -- you're then telling your TV it can find any IP not local to it by passing thru `192.168.8.1` -- which, in turn, knows about `192.168.1.x`, also whatever network your VPN exports, -and- everything else that should already be set up (via DHCP) via either the router (`192.168.1.112`).

This is not probable, but if your TV sets up DNS address to `192.168.1.112`, it is fine. The only important "pointers" that should be in the same `192.168.8.x` range is the gateway and its own IP address.

Again, this is just one of the possible solutions for your problem, using "clean routing" (that's me saying). It could work with NAT, and even port forwarding or a strange DMZ configuration, but in my opinion the option above would be the "cleanest" solution so that you know what goes where.

In the case your TV uses some broadcast-driven protocol to connect to devices, all the above solutions should not work, and you should instead turn your router into a "bridge", which is basically what I believe you stated you don't want to with *"I can simply connect the Nas to the new router and it's ok. But I would really not prefer"*. This, as you may already know, would just be a matter of plugging the cable from the WAN port to one of the LAN ones, and disabling either router's DHCP server (or you'd get "rogue DHCP" replies, getting IP conflicts, etc).

Sorry for the long answer. There's as much detail to it as one thinks possible. ;)